# Break for a while after two if

Tags: c, break

How can i break an infinity do..while after two if (if in if) statement?
For example:

```
do
{
   ...
   if (a)
   {
      if(b)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}
while(1);
```

I want to terminate while loop if b==true

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It seems to not break from the do..while

Comment: there's no problem, it will break the loop.

Comment: Your code should break properly after the `b` condition is met, there is no any additional syntax for this case

Comment: @GeoG392 it wil break the loop if a and b are not 0

Comment: This will only fail to work if you `break` is within *another* loop or `switch` -- it will break out of that one but not the outer `do`.  Unless you are trying to break if *only* `b` is true in which case you can't have it within the `if (a)`.  You could just do `do { ... } while (!b);`.

Comment: @GeoG392 "I want to terminate while loop if b==true" No problem! if ( b == true ) abort();

Comment: It seems like that a more likely problem is that the condition `b` (or `a`) is not what you think it is. Please show a complete example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loop to terminate if b is true, then b should be the only factor. But on your example, unless A is also true,it will never break. You need to separate the if statements